# Tank_Auth With Code Igniter Giving 404 on registration-success

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, tankauth

I'm working with CodeIgniter and Tank_Auth. I got the registration to work, but it looks like it's trying to load registration-success, and I'm not sure where that is.

In auth.php on line 239 I have

```
$this->tank_auth->notice('registration-success');
```

I see a registration-success.php in views/landing/registration-success.php. Is this the page it's trying to access? I'm getting a 404 when I submit a successful registration (I can see the user created in the db).

EDIT:
After resetting and updating my routes.php file, I see that I'm getting a 404 page not found error while the url in the browser points to index.php/auth. Is there something I'm supposed to route in order for this to work?

Currently I have the following in my routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';

$route['login'] = "/auth/login";
$route['logout'] = "/auth/logout";
$route['register'] = "/auth/register";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking at TA library and I don't see any `notice()` method or function. Also in `auth.php` (fresh download) I did not find any lines that contain `"notice"`.

Also note

1. that you have two `$route['default_controller']` in your `routes.php`.
2. that [routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) in CodeIgniter is **prioritized**.

Your `config/routes.php` should look like.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages/view";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['login'] = "/auth/login";
$route['logout'] = "/auth/logout";
$route['register'] = "/auth/register";

$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

see the last line ? it uses a "wild card", you had problem with that line because, it grabbed eg. `localhost/project/login` and "redirected" (routes do not **redirect**) to `localhost/project/pages/view/login` terefore you got `404`